# Sonarqube indicates violation of csharpsquid:S3649 - User-provided values should be sanitized before use in SQL statements

Tags: c#, sonarqube

In a sonarqube scan of our code, I have a number of violations of csharpsquid:S3649 - User-provided values should be sanitized before use in SQL statements.  I think that my code is compliant, can anyone else shed some light as to why this is flagged as non-compliant?

```
string connectionString = DatabaseContext.GetiXDataConnectionString();

string sql = "SELECT UserID FROM SystemUsers " +
             "Where WindowsLogonName = @WindowsLogon and DomainName = @WindowsDomain and " +
              "[Disabled] = 0";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
 conn.Open();

 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
 {
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@WindowsLogon", windowsUsername));
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@WindowsDomain", userDomain));
  object queryResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

  if (queryResult != null)
     return queryResult.ToString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It complains because the `sql` variable is not a constant. The issue will disappear if you change your code to (which in general is not a bad thing):

`const string sql = "..." + "..." + "...";`

S3649 is a very simple rule that raises when the executed SQL is not constant string. It is far from a real taint analysis check, but it can catch the simplest and most obvious mistakes.