# Sanitise SQL parameters

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have the following SQL query:

```
var query = @"select EMP.ID, EMP.NAME
        from DB_TEST.DBO.EMPLOYEE as EMP 
        inner join DB_TEST.DBO.DEPARTMENT as DEPT on EMP.ID = DEPT.EMP_ID and DEPT.LANG_CH_TAG = 'english'
        where DEPT.ID = @deptId
        group by EMP.ID, EMP.NAME;";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@deptId", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@deptId"].Value = 37;

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

When this block of code runs under Sonar, I have the following error:

> Make sure to sanitize the parameters of this SQL command.

I thought passing the parameters through the cmd.Parameters was a way of sanitizing it.

Any way of how to do this please?

Comment: I would honestly say that SonarCube is wrong in this case.  You are correctly using a prepared statement, and it isn't even your concern about sanitizing the parameter.  Rather, you are letting the database worry about how to bind the input value to the placeholder.  My recommendation: ignore SonarCube.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, but could it be barking about `DEPT.LANG_CH_TAG = 'english'` because `'english'` is not parameterized?

Comment: @dbc : Maybe, I will try it and see if sonar accepts the correction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sonarqube indicates violation of csharpsquid:S3649 - User-provided values should be sanitized before use in SQL statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282655/sonarqube-indicates-violation-of-csharpsquids3649-user-provided-values-should)

Answer (score 0):

Below Code is Sample For Get Data From database with ADO.net:

Change the method of getting the parameter.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString")) 
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) 
                    { 
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = @"select EMP.ID, EMP.NAME
            from DB_TEST.DBO.EMPLOYEE as EMP 
            inner join DB_TEST.DBO.DEPARTMENT as DEPT on EMP.ID = DEPT.EMP_ID and DEPT.LANG_CH_TAG = 'english'
            where DEPT.ID = @deptId
            group by EMP.ID, EMP.NAME;";  

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deptId", deptId);  

                        try
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                          var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        }
                        catch(SqlException e)
                        {
                            MessgeBox.Show(e.Message.ToString(), "Error Message");
                        }

                    } 
                }
```

Comment: Please, add some description.

Comment: You should explain why your solution doesn't rise the error from question.