# Create SQL with dynamic fields without getting Sonarqube issues

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sql-injection

In C# I need to create a SQL where the user can enter the names of the fields that he/she wants for filters and results.

Something like this:

```
var sql = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} = '{3}', fieldList, tableName, filterField, filterValue);
```

For the sake of simplicity, I have only one field to filter but the idea is that the user can specify more filters.

When I run the Sonarqube analysis it warns SQL injection issues, which is obvious, but as you know in this case I need to build the SQL statement from data that the user entered.

How can we weather this dynamic SQL with Sonarqube?

Comment: You use parameters. I don't know which implementation you need, but if it is MS SQL Server you would use [SqlParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Comment: Sonarqube can work with SqlServer. But if its library does not export SqlParameter you'll have to take a decision. In order to avoid injection issues, at least check the origin of every parameter. If there is no user input involved in any of these fields, consider switching off the warning in Profiles https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/24734/how-to-deactivate-a-rule-in-sonarqube and also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282655/sonarqube-indicates-violation-of-csharpsquids3649-user-provided-values-should

Comment: Data, even from a database or file or whatever, always comes from user input at some level. Not to mention issues like punctuation and other characters that can break a sql statement.